# Get array of all objects in a Javascript file

Tags: javascript, object

I was playing around with some Javascript code, when I stumbled upon a question: **Is there any way to find the amount of** `objects` **in any javascript file, and print them out of a function?**
I haven't found anything on the internet which suggests an answer to this, and I doubt that this is possible, but if anyone has an idea, I would be interested to see it.

Code example if that didn't make sense:

```
var str = "Hello World!"; 
var num = 3.14; 
var obj = {};

function printOutObjects() { 
  var objs = [];
  // Find objects in script...
  console.log(objs);
}
```

Comment: What should be logged there? `str,num,obj`? `obj`? `obj,objs`?

Comment: Do you want objects in closures as well? How about DOM elements? Do you want to include objects created as a side effect of operations, like prototypes? How about internal objects or emulated private properties, should that be included too? Basically everything in JS is also an object, like objects, arrays, date objects, functions and etc. Should those be included too? **TL;DR: Define what you mean by "object"** because in JS, pretty much *everything is an object*.

Comment: All of them if possible. @Scimonster

Comment: are you planning to use var when defining new object ? will every object be defined using new keyword ?

Comment: I'm not saying it's not possible. IMO, the best way to check statically is to create your own parser and parse the code for points where objects are created. However, you are parsing it statically. You won't know what happens when the code during runtime. Also, hijacking code on runtime (anti-defensive programming stuff) is very hacky as well, and highly depends on the code being hijacked.

Comment: Why would anyone need this? What do you plan to do with this?

Comment: What is the actual intension.? Two options i thinks of without complete understanding of your problem. 1) all variable will be defined in window property. By doing some logic we can get the variables. otherwise initialize the variable in seperate object itself.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, @JosephtheDreamer I was referring to `String`, `Number`, `Object` and `Function` objects.

Comment: @soktinpk Sorry if I didn't make this clear - I asked the question out of pure curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well ultimately everything is part of the `window` object, so as a theoretical exercise you could use the following, but it will get you *slightly* more than you bargained for (and may crash your computer):

```
var str = "Hello World!"; 
var num = 3.14; 
var obj = {};

function printOutObjects() { 
  var objs = [];
  objs.push(window);
  recurseObj(window, objs);
  console.log(objs);
}

function recurseObj(o, objs) {
  if(typeof(o) == "undefined" || o == null || typeof(o) == "string" || typeof(o) == "number") {
    return;
  }
  for(var c in o) {
    // handle security exceptions and whatever else may come up
    try {
      // stop computer crashing
      if(objs.length > 300) {
        return;
      }
      else {
        var obj = o[c];
        // Ensure its not already in the results
        if(objs.indexOf(obj) == -1) {
          objs.push(obj);
          recurseObj(obj, objs);
        }
      }
    } catch(e){}
  }
}

printOutObjects();
```

Tho I'm not sure why you would want to do this at all, and you could just log `window` in the console and drill down into it if you want to see what is in your page.

Comment: handle security exceptions and whatever else may come up !!

Comment: Suggesting this operation be async. Use web workers or defer them using timers.